# Help with adjusting the color selector for the UV Editor

Tags: modeling, uv

I'm currently working on a tutorial from Imphenzia on how to model a low-poly Mandalorian. I'm trying to change the color of it, but I don't know how to alter the set of points in order to pick the colors I want. What do I do?
[image]

[image]
Here's the tutorial I'm working on...

https://youtu.be/szIvkd1NBz4?t=271

Here's the file...
[image]](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rRRMnagy/)

Comment: In the UV editor, hit 'A' to select all the vertices then 'S' to scale and drag them down to a single point. Then 'G' to drag them onto the colour square that you need for your model.

Comment: Incidentally you would need to pack the image into your Blend file before saving it for us to be able to see it via File > External Data > Pack all into .blend.

Comment: If you're still having problems with this, I've finally found the description of how Imphenzia does his low-poly colouring using UVs [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8&t=132s).

Comment: I tried shrinking it down to one pixel, but I can't and I can't change the color either. What do I do?

Comment: Have you looked at the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8&t=132s) which explains the whole technique in my last comment?

Comment: Yes, but that's a different shape from the palette I have in my Blender file.

Comment: As I said in my second comment, the Blend file that you uploaded didn't have the image packed into it so I wasn't able to test it with your image, but before I posted that video link, I'd already downloaded the image that he used in his video and checked that it was the same and that it worked in your Blend file, so I've no idea what you're using!